# Making elements fit to Screen Resolution (CSS/HTML)

Tags: html, css

I made a website on my laptop, it is my first for University.

I really enjoy it, in just 3 days I gained a good amount of knowledge of HTML and CSS and made a navigation bar, and 3 simple boxes with images/information we had to do.

Little did I realise, is that the resolution will not stretch or adapt to other screens. I opened it on my PC and the monitor is 1080p, so my right text box had a wide gap in between it and the middle box. My banner at the top also was as it would be seen on my laptop, but not the width of my screen.

```
#banner {
background: url("../images/background.jpg") no-repeat center;
background-size:100%;
width: 1920px;
height: 200px;
min-width:700px;
max-width: 1920px;
```

If I make a width and height like this, will it adapt to the screen? Also, do I **NEED** the **width** and **height** if I include a **minimum** and **max**? An idea to make just this banner fit well would be a good answer, as I'll use the answer to edit my other elements.

Comment: you might consider looking at 'bootstrap'

Comment: If you want something to fit the screen width, you can look up 'vw' .

Comment: Use CSS media queries and define for different screen widths

Comment: It all depends what do you want to achieve, should this banner have constant height and width scaled to the viewport width or scale as whole proportionally.

Comment: @Picard Well, it's a banner at the top of the screen. The height can stay the same, it's the width. I also don't want it to stretch too much.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using percentage with height and width (width: 100%) rather than static sizes.  It will help with different screen sizes as well as changing the size of your browser.

Edit:  [simple demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/nwgbu/ff8wbasL/)

HTML:

```
<div id="test">
  <p id="par">
    Hello world!
  </p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#test{
  width: 50%;
}

#par{
  width: 100%;
  background-color: pink;
}
```

Comment: I did try the width and height, but then how does the element know how far to go and where to stop? Do I need to add a minimum and maximum?

Comment: If you set width to a percentage, it will base it off of whatever container it's in.  If you have it in a div, width: 100% will extend to the size of the div.  If it's directly in body, it will fill to the size of the browser.

Answer (score 1):

> If I make a width and height like this, will it adapt to the screen?

No, `px` units represent fixed widths. You can use percentage units to let element have x% of it's container width or height. Another option, less common also, is to use `vw` and `vh`, wich represent a percentage of the viewport's width and height respectively.

For your use case a `width: 100%; height: auto` will do. The image will expand to fill it's container and the height will change dynamically to allow the image to maintain it's aspect ratio.

However, a banner for a regular desktop with aspect ratio 16:9 or 16:10 will never look good in mobile. You may need to use media queries to show different images based on viewport width.

Take this as an example:

```css
.banner {
  width: 100%;
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
  .banner-mobile { display: none; }
}

@media (max-width: 599px) {
  .banner-desktop { display: none; }
}
```

```html
<img class='banner banner-desktop' src="https://placehold.it/600x200?text=imma_desktop_banner"/>
<img class='banner banner-mobile' src="https://placehold.it/200x200?text=imma_mobile_banner"/>
```

#### Demo

https://codepen.io/nicooga/full/pPWyJx/
Notice how resizing the window changes the banner shown.

#### Read

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/CSS/Media_queries

Comment: I think it would be even better to switch the images to a single div and change the background of the div with the media queries you made.

Comment: Okay, but let's say I have a box I want in a position, when I set the width to 100%, it covers the width of the whole page. I only want a box in the middle of my page. That box spreads wide, I don't want that. So how do I go about this issue?

Comment: For positioning you should use a separate family of properties: `position`, `top`, `left`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would set the banner width to 100%, background-size to 'cover' for the image to fill the banner area with its position centered:

```
#banner {
    background-image: url(http://placehold.it/1200x800);
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
}
```

You can play with the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/piotku/u4zdLkyw/1/